# Do record types normally degrade data migration performance?

Tags: record-type, migration

I am using SSIS and Kingswaysoft to migrate data from a sql server database to salesforce. I noticed that all my tasks were performant (~5 minute run times for 50 - 100k records) except for 1 where the destination object had record types enabled for it(after 30 mins only 3000 were inserted out of 55k). After I removed all the record types and reran the task it was as performant as the others.

Are there any others that have noticed this performance degradation while migrating data? Is this normal?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57062380/do-record-types-affect-the-performance-of-a-migration-with-kingswaysoft/57063272#57063272

Comment: Are you disabling triggers / workflow rules while loading the data? There could be processes that run when data with specific record types is loaded.

Comment: There are no processes that run on these objects

Comment: "sharing rules" that use those record types?

Comment: @cropredy the destination object is public read write